# Lottie ref in Expo (react native)

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I am trying to move my existing React Native (typescript) project  to Expo. Everything is working fine in Expo except modal with Lottie animation ( without expo it is working properly).

My code:

```
export const SuccessModal = ({isVisible = false, onAnimationFinish}: Props) => {
  let animation: any = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible) {
      animation.current.play();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={isVisible}
      backdropStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(230, 228, 253, 0.5)'}}>
      <LottieView
        ref={animation}
        source={require('../assets/success-lottie.json')}
        style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
        autoPlay={true}
        loop={false}
        onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

I guess the problem is with `ref={animation}` , because modal is being displayed, but animation is not moving - seems like `animation.current.play()` is not invoked in the effect. I tried `useRef(null)` and `useRef<LottieView | null>(null)` as suggested in other posts. Also tried to reinstall lottie with command:  `expo install lottie-react-native`.

Any ideas what might be wrong here? What is so specific for Expo?

Answer (score 0):

I think calling `animation.current.reset();` before `animation.current.play();` would do the trick.

I am using `const animation = useRef(null)` hook and got it working with Expo too.

However, initial play() was not working by default and I had did this trick to make it work as soon as component loads.

```
...
const animation = useRef(null);
...
useEffect(() => {
  animation.current?.reset();
  animation.current?.play();
}, []);
```